# Best Practices For Dealing With This Scenario

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection, feature-engineering, labels

I'm presently building a spam classifier. The model is unable to even overfit the training set at present. To investigate, I plotted the distributions of the model's features, and compared them across spammers and non-spammers.

I've noticed that the distributions for most features between the two classes are almost identical - suggesting many spammers look similar to non-spammers in terms of behavior. I suspect this confuses the model.

To counter this, I'm conducting more feature engineering, as well as some data re-labelling (not sure if my labels are trustworthy), to see if I can inject more signal into the model. I'm not sure if this is the best approach, and would appreciate any insights / reading material on how to deal with this situation. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to do more feature engineering, this might be a good resource to read - https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/10/feature-selection-techniques-in-machine-learning/

Comment: Also, it is very difficult to gauge what's going on without knowing the details of your dataset. If possible you can post some visualizations.